# Can I screencast over YouTube live?

Tags: youtube-live, screencasts

I'm trying to set up a live stream of my desktop (think live video tutorial) but I can't figure out any way to do this.  YouTube Live seems to only support webcam streaming.

Is there any way to natively stream my desktop live over YouTube without having to add a 3rd party application first?

Comment: See [Create a live stream](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853700?hl=en-GB) on YouTube Help.

Comment: Thanks, that link appears to have confirmed that what I'm looking for is not possible.  Seems Youtube only supports native streaming of mobile devices or webcams, but not your desktop (at least not anymore as far as I can tell).  If anyone knows otherwise, I'd sure love to hear about it.

Comment: You should also what can be done with Open Broadcaster Software (OBS): [How to stream to Youtube](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/guide-how-to-stream-to-youtube.4333/) and [How To: Livestream on YouTube with OBS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyVuDiSE-l0).

Comment: Yeah I just am trying to not have to add another software component if I don't have to.  My machine is bogged down enough as it is.

Comment: So for reasons I don't understand, the next day the ability to share my screen on Youtube Live was working.  So, it can indeed screencast without any additional software.  It's a bit clunky IMO (using Google Hangouts), but it works.